# Zend email with attachment not sending on shared server

Tags: zend-framework

I am creating an email with an attachment using Zend Mail.  The email is sending on my local install but it is not working on a shared server.

In the error log I get the following - PHP Warning:  include(Zend/PDF.php): failed to open stream

Here is some of the code I am using for the email attachment:

```
$pdf = $this->createAttachment($params, "1");
$at = $this->mail->createAttachment($pdf->render());
$at->type = 'application/pdf';
$at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$at->filename = 'invoice.pdf';

function createAttachment($params, $type)
{
     $pdf = Zend_PDF::load("/system/assets/template.pdf");
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```
Zend_Pdf::load("/system/assets/template.pdf");
```

(note case of 'Pdf'). I'm guessing you're using a case insensitive file system locally but case sensitive on your shared server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. That's exactly what happened (win on local and debian on the remote server). I should have thought of that. Thanks again!